# The import org.openqa cannot be resolved

Tags: java, selenium

```
package ChromeWebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ChromeWebDrivers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
        
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());          
        driver.close();         
        
    }    
}
```

I m having java 16.0.1 eclipse & have imported external jar files but still getting this issue.

Comment: that means that that class is not on your classpath. are you using maven/gradle/... ?

Comment: imported external jar files - did you add the jars manually? or are using maven or gradle?

Comment: No i m not using maven/gradle i have imported jars manually

Comment: then chances are you did something wrong, because you may have imported the jar with that class, but it's not being found.

Comment: Did you configure all the thing in properly way? the CLASSPATH point on the jars folder? maybe this web will help you to do that.. https://tutoringcenter.cs.usfca.edu/resources/adding-user-libraries-in-eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver = new WebDriver();
```

WebDriver is an **interface**, you can not create object of it.

replace that with :

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

and your  `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");`

`.exe` is missing (if you are on Windows )and you need to give full path like this :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: initially i was using WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); i was getting Multiple following error : markers at this line
 - WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type
 - ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a 
  type

Comment: Then those are the actual errors, you can not simply do `new WebDriver();`