# org.openqa.selenium not accesible

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jar, selenium-chromedriver

once hover at error no option for import org.openqa. Stated that not accessible.

[image]

Comment: Hope this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68013289/the-import-org-openqa-cannot-be-resolved